# Implementing NSUndoManager with Paint Application

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, undo-redo, nsundomanager

I am new to iOS and building a paint application.

Everything goes ok..but I am unable to implement `NSUndoManager` in my application for `undo` and `redo` purpose.

The problem is that I am unable to store the previous state of painting for undo.

Here is the code

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

mouseSwiped = NO;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.tempDrawImage];
[[self.undoManage prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] 
touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

mouseSwiped = YES;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.tempDrawImage];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 
self.view.frame.size.height)];
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
lastPoint = currentPoint;
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tempDrawImage.frame.size);
[self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:
CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,   self.view.frame.size.height) 
blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[[self.undoManage prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] touchesMoved:touches 
withEvent:event];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
-(void)undo
{
[self.undoManage undo];
}
-(void)redo
{
[self.undoManage redo];
}
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  The data you should be recording during the touches actions should be the *brushstrokes* of the user (with associated attributes like brush colour, brush width, etc.).  Then in the `[UIView drawRect:]` subclass you apply these brushstrokes to create the "picture".

Comment: And to actually address your question; the undo/redo applies to these brushstrokes you have recorded.

Comment: How to do that... means passing brush colour, brush width etc in NSUndoManager.

Comment: No, you need to create a custom "model" object, that records the stroke and attributes, and you can probably store these models in a mutable array.